# How to populate a treeview from a XML file with multiple child nodes?

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-parsing, treeview, populate

I´m trying to populate a TreeView component in VB.NET from a XML file. It´s a large XML file and I chopped it up in order to give you guys an idea about how it is structured. I´m new to VB.NET so I´m having a hard time to figure this out. Below there´s an image of the order I expect this data to be shown in the TreeView, and I added some arrows so you can understand where the data is supposed to come from in the XML structure.

I found and tried to adapt a code I got from a Microsoft tutorial, but it´s based on a much simpler XML structure and it´s not working with my file.

The arrows in the image are being shown out of synch with the XML tags & nodes but my goal was to avoid the arrows and rectangles overlaping each other making the picture unreadable.

When we have a node named "Cutter" it´s a different type of component, and more than one may be comprised within the current "Cutter" or "Holder" node, so they are separated by the "Reference" tag. If it´s named "Holder" it´s another component type on the tool stackup... Every new tool starts with an element named "Tool".

Below the picture what I´m trying to do in the code:

[Tree View Explanation](http://www.screencast.com/t/ucr4Z4a77L7)

```
Private Sub btnSearchTLS_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearchTLS.Click

        Try
            ' SECTION 1. Create a DOM Document and load the XML data into it.
            Dim dom As New XmlDocument()
            dom.Load(txtFileOpenTLS_2.Text)

            ' SECTION 2. Initialize the treeview control.
            tviewToolIDs.Nodes.Clear()
            tviewToolIDs.Nodes.Add(New TreeNode(dom.DocumentElement.Name))
            Dim tNode As New TreeNode()
            tNode = tviewToolIDs.Nodes(0)

            ' SECTION 3. Populate the TreeView with the DOM nodes.
            AddNode(dom.DocumentElement, tNode)
            tviewToolIDs.ExpandAll()

        Catch xmlEx As XmlException
            MessageBox.Show(xmlEx.Message)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub AddNode(ByRef inXmlNode As XmlNode, ByRef inTreeNode As TreeNode)
        Dim xNode As XmlNode
        Dim tNode As TreeNode
        Dim nodeList As XmlNodeList
        Dim i As Integer

        ' Loop through the XML nodes until the leaf is reached.
        ' Add the nodes to the TreeView during the looping process.
        If inXmlNode.HasChildNodes() Then
            nodeList = inXmlNode.ChildNodes
            For i = 0 To nodeList.Count - 1
                xNode = inXmlNode.(i)
                inTreeNode.Nodes.Add(New TreeNode(xNode.Name))
                tNode = inTreeNode.Nodes(i)
                AddNode(xNode, tNode)
            Next
        Else
            ' Here you need to pull the data from the XmlNode based on the
            ' type of node, whether attribute values are required, and so forth.
            inTreeNode.Text = (inXmlNode.OuterXml).Trim
        End If
    End Sub
```

Here´s the XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<ToolLibrary Version="7.3">
    <Tools>
    <Tool ID="100004" Units="Millimeter">
      <Description>100004</Description>
      <Teeth>1</Teeth>
      <Type>Turning</Type>
      <Cutter>
        <Reference ID="12140 - N123G2-0318-0008">
          <FileName>TBT_MASTER_LIBRARY.tls</FileName>
          <ToolID>Torneamento - Insertos paramétricos</ToolID>
          <EntityName>12140 - N123G2-0318-0008</EntityName>
          <Origin>
            <X>34.2</X>
            <Y>0</Y>
            <Z>-82.3</Z>
          </Origin>
          <Rotation>
            <X>0</X>
            <Y>-90</Y>
            <Z>0</Z>
          </Rotation>
          <NoSpin>0</NoSpin>
          <Alternate>Off</Alternate>
        </Reference>
      </Cutter>
      <Holder>
        <Reference ID="12135 - C5-570-32-LF">
          <FileName>TBT_MASTER_LIBRARY.tls</FileName>
          <ToolID>Holders &amp; Acessorios</ToolID>
          <EntityName>12135 - C5-570-32-LF</EntityName>
          <NoSpin>0</NoSpin>
          <Alternate>Off</Alternate>
        </Reference>
        <Reference ID="12139 - 570-32L123G18B130A">
          <FileName>TBT_MASTER_LIBRARY.tls</FileName>
          <ToolID>Holders &amp; Acessorios</ToolID>
          <EntityName>12139 - 570-32L123G18B130A</EntityName>
          <Origin>
            <X>21</X>
            <Y>0</Y>
            <Z>-42</Z>
          </Origin>
          <NoSpin>0</NoSpin>
          <Alternate>Off</Alternate>
        </Reference>
      </Holder>
      <DrivenPoint ID="1">
        <Type>-1</Type>
        <Radius>0</Radius>
        <X>35</X>
        <Y>0</Y>
        <Z>-83.1</Z>
      </DrivenPoint>
      <DrivenPoint ID="2">
        <Type>-1</Type>
        <Radius>0</Radius>
        <X>31.82</X>
        <Y>0</Y>
        <Z>-83.1</Z>
      </DrivenPoint>
      <CutterCompensation ID="1">0.8</CutterCompensation>
      <CutterCompensation ID="2">0.8</CutterCompensation>
    </Tool>
    <Tool ID="100171" Units="Millimeter">
      <Description>100171</Description>
      <Teeth>1</Teeth>
      <Type>Turning</Type>
      <Cutter>
        <Reference ID="12349 - CNMG120412">
          <FileName>TBT_MASTER_LIBRARY.tls</FileName>
          <ToolID>Torneamento - Insertos paramétricos</ToolID>
          <EntityName>12349 - CNMG120412</EntityName>
          <Origin>
            <X>-35.8</X>
            <Y>0</Y>
            <Z>-291.8</Z>
          </Origin>
          <Rotation>
            <X>0</X>
            <Y>-5</Y>
            <Z>0</Z>
          </Rotation>
          <NoSpin>0</NoSpin>
          <Alternate>Off</Alternate>
        </Reference>
      </Cutter>
      <Holder>
        <Reference ID="11977 - C6-390.410-100-110A">
          <FileName>TBT_MASTER_LIBRARY.tls</FileName>
          <ToolID>Holders &amp; Acessorios</ToolID>
          <EntityName>11977 - C6-390.410-100-110A</EntityName>
          <NoSpin>0</NoSpin>
          <Alternate>Off</Alternate>
        </Reference>
        <Reference ID="11978 - C6-570-2C-60-148-40L">
          <FileName>TBT_MASTER_LIBRARY.tls</FileName>
          <ToolID>Holders &amp; Acessorios</ToolID>
          <EntityName>11978 - C6-570-2C-60-148-40L</EntityName>
          <Origin>
            <X>0</X>
            <Y>0</Y>
            <Z>-110</Z>
          </Origin>
          <NoSpin>0</NoSpin>
          <Alternate>Off</Alternate>
        </Reference>
        <Reference ID="11979 - SL-PCLNL-40-12HP">
          <FileName>TBT_MASTER_LIBRARY.tls</FileName>
          <ToolID>Holders &amp; Acessorios</ToolID>
          <EntityName>11979 - SL-PCLNL-40-12HP</EntityName>
          <Origin>
            <X>-10</X>
            <Y>0</Y>
            <Z>-258</Z>
          </Origin>
          <NoSpin>0</NoSpin>
          <Alternate>Off</Alternate>
        </Reference>
      </Holder>
      <DrivenPoint ID="1">
        <Type>-1</Type>
        <Radius>0</Radius>
        <X>-37</X>
        <Y>0</Y>
        <Z>-293</Z>
      </DrivenPoint>
      <DrivenPoint ID="2">
        <Type>-1</Type>
        <Radius>0</Radius>
        <X>-37</X>
        <Y>0</Y>
        <Z>-293</Z>
      </DrivenPoint>
      <CutterCompensation ID="1">1.2</CutterCompensation>
      <CutterCompensation ID="2">1.2</CutterCompensation>
    </Tool>
    <Tool ID="100178" Units="Millimeter">
      <Description>100178</Description>
      <Teeth>8</Teeth>
      <Type>Milling</Type>
      <Cutter>
        <Reference ID="10084 - R90MT-12-05-RM">
          <FileName>TBT_MASTER_LIBRARY.tls</FileName>
          <ToolID>Rotativas - Insertos Paramétricos</ToolID>
          <EntityName>10084 - R90MT-12-05-RM</EntityName>
          <Origin>
            <X>44</X>
            <Y>0</Y>
            <Z>-614</Z>
          </Origin>
          <NoSpin>0</NoSpin>
          <Alternate>Off</Alternate>
        </Reference>
        <Reference ID="10084 - R90MT-12-05-RM1">
          <FileName>TBT_MASTER_LIBRARY.tls</FileName>
          <ToolID>Rotativas - Insertos Paramétricos</ToolID>
          <EntityName>10084 - R90MT-12-05-RM</EntityName>
          <Origin>
            <X>31.112698</X>
            <Y>-31.112698</Y>
            <Z>-614</Z>
          </Origin>
          <Rotation>
            <X>0</X>
            <Y>0</Y>
            <Z>-45</Z>
          </Rotation>
          <NoSpin>0</NoSpin>
          <Alternate>Off</Alternate>
        </Reference>
        <Reference ID="10084 - R90MT-12-05-RM11">
          <FileName>TBT_MASTER_LIBRARY.tls</FileName>
          <ToolID>Rotativas - Insertos Paramétricos</ToolID>
          <EntityName>10084 - R90MT-12-05-RM</EntityName>
          <Origin>
            <X>31.112698</X>
            <Y>31.112698</Y>
            <Z>-614</Z>
          </Origin>
          <Rotation>
            <X>0</X>
            <Y>0</Y>
            <Z>45</Z>
          </Rotation>
          <NoSpin>0</NoSpin>
          <Alternate>Off</Alternate>
        </Reference>
        <Reference ID="10084 - R90MT-12-05-RM12">
          <FileName>TBT_MASTER_LIBRARY.tls</FileName>
          <ToolID>Rotativas - Insertos Paramétricos</ToolID>
          <EntityName>10084 - R90MT-12-05-RM</EntityName>
          <Origin>
            <X>0</X>
            <Y>-44</Y>
            <Z>-614</Z>
          </Origin>
          <Rotation>
            <X>0</X>
            <Y>0</Y>
            <Z>-90</Z>
          </Rotation>
          <NoSpin>0</NoSpin>
          <Alternate>Off</Alternate>
        </Reference>
        <Reference ID="10084 - R90MT-12-05-RM13">
          <FileName>TBT_MASTER_LIBRARY.tls</FileName>
          <ToolID>Rotativas - Insertos Paramétricos</ToolID>
          <EntityName>10084 - R90MT-12-05-RM</EntityName>
          <Origin>
            <X>0</X>
            <Y>44</Y>
            <Z>-614</Z>
          </Origin>
          <Rotation>
            <X>0</X>
            <Y>0</Y>
            <Z>90</Z>
          </Rotation>
          <NoSpin>0</NoSpin>
          <Alternate>Off</Alternate>
        </Reference>
        <Reference ID="10084 - R90MT-12-05-RM14">
          <FileName>TBT_MASTER_LIBRARY.tls</FileName>
          <ToolID>Rotativas - Insertos Paramétricos</ToolID>
          <EntityName>10084 - R90MT-12-05-RM</EntityName>
          <Origin>
            <X>-31.112698</X>
            <Y>31.112698</Y>
            <Z>-614</Z>
          </Origin>
          <Rotation>
            <X>0</X>
            <Y>0</Y>
            <Z>135</Z>
          </Rotation>
          <NoSpin>0</NoSpin>
          <Alternate>Off</Alternate>
        </Reference>
        <Reference ID="10084 - R90MT-12-05-RM15">
          <FileName>TBT_MASTER_LIBRARY.tls</FileName>
          <ToolID>Rotativas - Insertos Paramétricos</ToolID>
          <EntityName>10084 - R90MT-12-05-RM</EntityName>
          <Origin>
            <X>-44</X>
            <Y>0</Y>
            <Z>-614</Z>
          </Origin>
          <Rotation>
            <X>0</X>
            <Y>0</Y>
            <Z>180</Z>
          </Rotation>
          <NoSpin>0</NoSpin>
          <Alternate>Off</Alternate>
        </Reference>
        <Reference ID="10084 - R90MT-12-05-RM">
          <FileName>TBT_MASTER_LIBRARY.tls</FileName>
          <ToolID>Rotativas - Insertos Paramétricos</ToolID>
          <EntityName>10084 - R90MT-12-05-RM</EntityName>
          <Origin>
            <X>-31.1127</X>
            <Y>-31.1127</Y>
            <Z>-614</Z>
          </Origin>
          <Rotation>
            <X>0</X>
            <Y>0</Y>
            <Z>-135</Z>
          </Rotation>
          <NoSpin>0</NoSpin>
          <Alternate>Off</Alternate>
        </Reference>
      </Cutter>
      <Holder>
        <Reference ID="11974 - C8-390.410-100 120A">
          <FileName>TBT_MASTER_LIBRARY.tls</FileName>
          <ToolID>Holders &amp; Acessorios</ToolID>
          <EntityName>11974 - C8-390.410-100 120A</EntityName>
          <NoSpin>0</NoSpin>
          <Alternate>Off</Alternate>
        </Reference>
        <Reference ID="12001 - C8-391.01-80 065">
          <FileName>TBT_MASTER_LIBRARY.tls</FileName>
          <ToolID>Holders &amp; Acessorios</ToolID>
          <EntityName>12001 - C8-391.01-80 065</EntityName>
          <Origin>
            <X>0</X>
            <Y>0</Y>
            <Z>-120</Z>
          </Origin>
          <NoSpin>0</NoSpin>
          <Alternate>Off</Alternate>
        </Reference>
        <Reference ID="12001 - C8-391.01-80 065">
          <FileName>TBT_MASTER_LIBRARY.tls</FileName>
          <ToolID>Holders &amp; Acessorios</ToolID>
          <EntityName>12001 - C8-391.01-80 065</EntityName>
          <Origin>
            <X>0</X>
            <Y>0</Y>
            <Z>-185</Z>
          </Origin>
          <NoSpin>0</NoSpin>
          <Alternate>Off</Alternate>
        </Reference>
        <Reference ID="12002 - C8-391.05-CD-32-320">
          <FileName>TBT_MASTER_LIBRARY.tls</FileName>
          <ToolID>Holders &amp; Acessorios</ToolID>
          <EntityName>12002 - C8-391.05-CD-32-320</EntityName>
          <Origin>
            <X>0</X>
            <Y>0</Y>
            <Z>-250</Z>
          </Origin>
          <NoSpin>0</NoSpin>
          <Alternate>Off</Alternate>
        </Reference>
        <Reference ID="10707 - FCM-D100-32-11">
          <FileName>TBT_MASTER_LIBRARY.tls</FileName>
          <ToolID>Holders &amp; Acessorios</ToolID>
          <EntityName>10707 - FCM-D100-32-11</EntityName>
          <Origin>
            <X>0</X>
            <Y>0</Y>
            <Z>-570</Z>
          </Origin>
          <NoSpin>0</NoSpin>
          <Alternate>Off</Alternate>
        </Reference>
      </Holder>
      <DrivenPoint ID="1">
        <Type>-1</Type>
        <Radius>0</Radius>
        <X>0</X>
        <Y>0</Y>
        <Z>-620</Z>
      </DrivenPoint>
      <DrivenPoint ID="2">
        <Type>-1</Type>
        <Radius>0</Radius>
        <X>0</X>
        <Y>0</Y>
        <Z>-620</Z>
      </DrivenPoint>
      <CutterCompensation ID="1">50</CutterCompensation>
      <CutterCompensation ID="2">50</CutterCompensation>
    </Tool>
    <Tool ID="100192" Units="Millimeter">
      <Description>100192</Description>
      <Teeth>1</Teeth>
      <Type>Milling</Type>
      <Cutter>
        <Reference ID="10087 - 880-05-03-05H-C-GM">
          <FileName>TBT_MASTER_LIBRARY.tls</FileName>
          <ToolID>Rotativas - Insertos Paramétricos</ToolID>
          <EntityName>10087 - 880-05-03-05H-C-GM</EntityName>
          <Origin>
            <X>-7.9</X>
            <Y>0</Y>
            <Z>-233.5</Z>
          </Origin>
          <Rotation>
            <X>0</X>
            <Y>0</Y>
            <Z>180</Z>
          </Rotation>
          <NoSpin>0</NoSpin>
          <Alternate>Off</Alternate>
        </Reference>
        <Reference ID="10088 - 880-05 03 W05H-P-GM">
          <FileName>TBT_MASTER_LIBRARY.tls</FileName>
          <ToolID>Rotativas - Insertos Paramétricos</ToolID>
          <EntityName>10088 - 880-05 03 W05H-P-GM</EntityName>
          <Origin>
            <X>12</X>
            <Y>0</Y>
            <Z>-233.5</Z>
          </Origin>
          <NoSpin>0</NoSpin>
          <Alternate>Off</Alternate>
        </Reference>
      </Cutter>
      <Holder>
        <Reference ID="12007 - C4-390.410-100-090A">
          <FileName>TBT_MASTER_LIBRARY.tls</FileName>
          <ToolID>Holders &amp; Acessorios</ToolID>
          <EntityName>12007 - C4-390.410-100-090A</EntityName>
          <NoSpin>0</NoSpin>
          <Alternate>Off</Alternate>
        </Reference>
        <Reference ID="12033 - 880-D2500C4-04">
          <FileName>TBT_MASTER_LIBRARY.tls</FileName>
          <ToolID>Holders &amp; Acessorios</ToolID>
          <EntityName>12033 - 880-D2500C4-04</EntityName>
          <Origin>
            <X>0</X>
            <Y>0</Y>
            <Z>-90</Z>
          </Origin>
          <NoSpin>0</NoSpin>
          <Alternate>Off</Alternate>
        </Reference>
      </Holder>
      <DrivenPoint ID="1">
        <Type>-1</Type>
        <Radius>0</Radius>
        <X>0</X>
        <Y>0</Y>
        <Z>-234</Z>
      </DrivenPoint>
    </Tool>
    <Tool ID="801154" Units="Millimeter">
      <Description>801154</Description>
      <Teeth>1</Teeth>
      <Type>Turning</Type>
      <Cutter>
        <Reference ID="11325 - MKI-176807-13_4.4">
          <FileName>TBT_MASTER_LIBRARY.tls</FileName>
          <ToolID>Torneamento - Insertos 3D</ToolID>
          <EntityName>11325 - MKI-176807-13_4.4</EntityName>
          <Origin>
            <X>-5.18</X>
            <Y>0</Y>
            <Z>-225</Z>
          </Origin>
          <NoSpin>0</NoSpin>
          <Alternate>Off</Alternate>
        </Reference>
      </Cutter>
      <Holder>
        <Reference ID="12016 - 392.410-100-ASHL-32">
          <FileName>TBT_MASTER_LIBRARY.tls</FileName>
          <ToolID>Holders &amp; Acessorios</ToolID>
          <EntityName>12016 - 392.410-100-ASHL-32</EntityName>
          <NoSpin>0</NoSpin>
          <Alternate>Off</Alternate>
        </Reference>
        <Reference ID="11328 - MKS-366807-18">
          <FileName>TBT_MASTER_LIBRARY.tls</FileName>
          <ToolID>Holders &amp; Acessorios</ToolID>
          <EntityName>11328 - MKS-366807-18</EntityName>
          <Origin>
            <X>-8</X>
            <Y>0</Y>
            <Z>-55</Z>
          </Origin>
          <NoSpin>0</NoSpin>
          <Alternate>Off</Alternate>
        </Reference>
      </Holder>
      <DrivenPoint ID="2">
        <Type>-1</Type>
        <Radius>0</Radius>
        <X>-2.980037</X>
        <Y>0</Y>
        <Z>-225</Z>
      </DrivenPoint>
      <DrivenPoint ID="1">
        <Type>-1</Type>
        <Radius>0</Radius>
        <X>-7.380037</X>
        <Y>0</Y>
        <Z>-225</Z>
      </DrivenPoint>
      <CutterCompensation ID="1">1.5</CutterCompensation>
      <CutterCompensation ID="2">1.5</CutterCompensation>
    </Tool>
  </Tools>
 </ToolLibrary>
```

What do I have to do in the code above (Considering it´s the right code - Feel free to come up with a new approach) to make my TreeView to be populated like shown in the image?

I´m sorry for asking for a thing possibly already covered, I did a search and could not find something that could work with my XML example.

Tks in advance,

Daniel

Comment: J, Thank you VERY MUCH! It worked well and I learned a lot from your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I improved the output.  See code below

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text.Encoding
Public Class Form1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            ' SECTION 1. Create a DOM Document and load the XML data into it

            Dim reader As New StreamReader(FILENAME, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
            Dim dom As XDocument = XDocument.Load(reader)            ' SECTION 2. Initialize the treeview control.
            TreeView1.Nodes.Clear()
            TreeView1.Nodes.Add(New TreeNode(dom.Root.Name.LocalName))
            Dim tNode As New TreeNode()
            tNode = TreeView1.Nodes(0)
            Dim tools As XElement = dom.Descendants("Tools").FirstOrDefault()
            ' SECTION 3. Populate the TreeView with the DOM nodes.
            AddNode(tools, tNode)
            TreeView1.CollapseAll()
            ExpandToLevel(TreeView1.Nodes, 1)


        Catch xmlEx As XmlException
            MessageBox.Show(xmlEx.Message)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub AddNode(ByRef inXmlNode As XElement, ByRef inTreeNode As TreeNode)
        Dim elements As List(Of XElement)

        ' Loop through the XML nodes until the leaf is reached.
        ' Add the nodes to the TreeView during the looping process.
        If inXmlNode.Descendants.Count > 0 Then
            elements = inXmlNode.Descendants("Tool").ToList()
            For Each element As XElement In elements
                Dim ID As String = element.Attribute("ID").Value
                Dim Description As String = element.Element("Description").Value
                Dim Teeth As String = element.Element("Teeth").Value
                Dim Type As String = element.Element("Type").Value

                Dim newNode As TreeNode = inTreeNode.Nodes.Add(ID & " (" & String.Join(", ", {Description, "Teeth : " & Teeth, "Type : " & Type}) & ")")

                If Not element.Element("Cutter") Is Nothing Then
                    Dim Cutters As List(Of XElement) = element.Element("Cutter").Elements("Reference").ToList()
                    Dim CutterBranch As TreeNode = newNode.Nodes.Add("Cutter")
                    For Each Cutter As XElement In Cutters
                        Dim Cutter_ID As String = Cutter.Attribute("ID")
                        CutterBranch.Nodes.Add(Cutter_ID)
                    Next Cutter
                End If

                If Not element.Element("Holder") Is Nothing Then
                    Dim Holders As List(Of XElement) = element.Element("Holder").Elements("Reference").ToList()

                    Dim HolderBranch As TreeNode = newNode.Nodes.Add("Holder")
                    For Each Holder As XElement In Holders
                        Dim Holder_ID As String = Holder.Attribute("ID")
                        HolderBranch.Nodes.Add(Holder_ID)
                    Next Holder
                End If
            Next element
        Else
            ' Here you need to pull the data from the XmlNode based on the
            ' type of node, whether attribute values are required, and so forth.
            inTreeNode.Text = (inXmlNode.ToString()).Trim
        End If
    End Sub
    Sub ExpandToLevel(nodes As TreeNodeCollection, level As Integer)
        If level > 0 Then
            For Each node As TreeNode In nodes
                node.Expand()
                ExpandToLevel(node.Nodes, level - 1)
            Next node
        End If
    End Sub
    Sub treeView1_AfterExpand(sender As Object, e As TreeViewEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.AfterExpand
        If Not e.Node.Parent Is Nothing Then
            e.Node.ExpandAll()
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
​
```

Comment: J,I´m trying it right now. Many thanks I´m learning alot from your code!

Comment: It works as expected! More than that, I was able to learn a lot from your code!

Comment: The people who run the website wouldn't approve all the changes I made.  I edited the original response, but it didn't get approved.  So I simply created a new response.

Comment: jdweng, I have some XML files where the <Cutter> element or the <Holder> sections does not exist. When your algorithm bumps into a <Tool> with this scenario, I get an exception "Object Reference not set to an instance of object".  It happens on either "Dim Cutters As List(Of XElement) = element.Element("Cutter").Elements("Reference").ToList()" or "  Dim Holders As List(Of XElement) = element.Element("Holder").Elements("Reference").ToList()" whenever <holder> or <cutter> sections are not present for a given <Tool> element. How can I skip if they are not present and move to next <tool>?

Comment: It worked like a charm... I had another exception caused by a similar cause and your last mod taught me how to handle it... I´m sorry for bothering that much by I definitely learned a lot about XML handling from your examples...

Answer (score 1):

Use this.

Const FILENAME As String = "C:\joy\Web.config.xml"
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            ' SECTION 1. Create a DOM Document and load the XML data into it

```
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(FILENAME, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
        Dim dom As XDocument = XDocument.Load(reader)            ' SECTION 2. Initialize the treeview control.
        Dim rootNode As New TreeNode(dom.Root.Name.LocalName)
        TreeView1.Nodes.Clear()
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(rootNode)
        Dim ch = dom.Root.Elements()

        For Each obj As XElement In ch
            Dim chNode As New TreeNode(obj.Name.LocalName)
            addNode(obj, chNode, rootNode)
        Next

        rootNode.ExpandAll()

    Catch xmlEx As XmlException
        MessageBox.Show(xmlEx.Message)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub


Public Sub addNode(xmlParent As XElement, node As TreeNode, parentNode As TreeNode)
    parentNode.Nodes.Add(node)

    For Each item In xmlParent.Elements()
        Dim chNode As New TreeNode(item.Name.LocalName)
        If item.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Element Then
            For Each attr In item.Attributes
                chNode.Nodes.Add(New TreeNode(attr.Name.ToString() + " = " + attr.Value))
            Next
        End If
        addNode(item, chNode, node)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Please supplement your answer with some explanations and fix your indentation at the code blocks top. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I added some filtering.  To do this I change from XmlDocument to linq XDocument.  I extracted a bunch of object in the code but didn't put all of them into the treeview.  Left that to you.

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text.Encoding
Public Class Form1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            ' SECTION 1. Create a DOM Document and load the XML data into it

            Dim reader As New StreamReader(FILENAME, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
            Dim dom As XDocument = XDocument.Load(reader)            ' SECTION 2. Initialize the treeview control.
            TreeView1.Nodes.Clear()
            TreeView1.Nodes.Add(New TreeNode(dom.Root.Name.LocalName))
            Dim tNode As New TreeNode()
            tNode = TreeView1.Nodes(0)
            Dim tools As XElement = dom.Descendants("Tools").FirstOrDefault()
            ' SECTION 3. Populate the TreeView with the DOM nodes.
            AddNode(tools, tNode)
            TreeView1.ExpandAll()

        Catch xmlEx As XmlException
            MessageBox.Show(xmlEx.Message)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub AddNode(ByRef inXmlNode As XElement, ByRef inTreeNode As TreeNode)
        Dim elements As List(Of XElement)
        Dim tNode As TreeNode
        Dim nodeList As XmlNodeList
        Dim i As Integer

        ' Loop through the XML nodes until the leaf is reached.
        ' Add the nodes to the TreeView during the looping process.
        If inXmlNode.Descendants.Count > 0 Then
            elements = inXmlNode.Descendants("Tool").ToList()
            For Each element As XElement In elements
                Dim ID As String = element.Attribute("ID").Value
                Dim Description As String = element.Element("Description").Value
                Dim Teeth As String = element.Element("Teeth").Value
                Dim Type As String = element.Element("Type").Value

                Dim CutterReference As XElement = element.Element("Cutter").Element("Reference")
                Dim Cutter_ID As String = CutterReference.Attribute("ID")
                Dim HolderReference As XElement = element.Element("Holder").Element("Reference")
                Dim Holder_ID As String = HolderReference.Attribute("ID")


                Dim newNode As TreeNode = inTreeNode.Nodes.Add(Description)
                newNode.Nodes.Add("Cutter :" & Cutter_ID)
                newNode.Nodes.Add("Holder :" & Holder_ID)


            Next element
        Else
            ' Here you need to pull the data from the XmlNode based on the
            ' type of node, whether attribute values are required, and so forth.
            inTreeNode.Text = (inXmlNode.ToString()).Trim
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Hi jdweng, Thanks for your prompt response... Actually now I´m getting every node which is not what I´m looking for... I´ll try to see if I can filter this... but I admit I´m clueless about how to do it... Tks!

Answer (score 0):

I added a sorter to the code.  Never did that before.  Thought it might make it easier to use.  I sorted by Tool Type (Turning, Milling) and number of teeth

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text.Encoding
Public Class Form1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            ' SECTION 1. Create a DOM Document and load the XML data into it

            Dim reader As New StreamReader(FILENAME, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
            Dim dom As XDocument = XDocument.Load(reader)            ' SECTION 2. Initialize the treeview control.
            TreeView1.Nodes.Clear()
            TreeView1.Nodes.Add(New Tool(dom.Root.Name.LocalName, Tool.NType.Root))
            Dim tNode As New Tool(False)
            tNode = TreeView1.Nodes(0)
            Dim tools As XElement = dom.Descendants("Tools").FirstOrDefault()
            ' SECTION 3. Populate the TreeView with the DOM nodes.
            AddNode(tools, tNode)
            TreeView1.TreeViewNodeSorter = NodeSorter.DefaultSorter
            TreeView1.Sort()
            TreeView1.CollapseAll()
            ExpandToLevel(TreeView1.Nodes, 1)


        Catch xmlEx As XmlException
            MessageBox.Show(xmlEx.Message)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub AddNode(ByRef inXmlNode As XElement, ByRef inTreeNode As Tool)
        Dim elements As List(Of XElement)

        ' Loop through the XML nodes until the leaf is reached.
        ' Add the nodes to the TreeView during the looping process.
        If inXmlNode.Descendants.Count > 0 Then
            elements = inXmlNode.Descendants("Tool").ToList()
            For Each element As XElement In elements

                Dim newTool As New Tool(Tool.NType.Tool)
                newTool.ID = element.Attribute("ID").Value
                newTool.Description = element.Element("Description").Value
                newTool.Teeth = element.Element("Teeth").Value
                newTool.Type = element.Element("Type").Value
                newTool.Text = newTool.ID & " (" & String.Join(", ", {newTool.Description, "Type : " & newTool.Type, "Teeth : " & newTool.Teeth}) & ")"

                inTreeNode.Nodes.Add(newTool)

                If Not element.Element("Cutter") Is Nothing Then
                    Dim Cutters As List(Of XElement) = element.Element("Cutter").Elements("Reference").ToList()
                    Dim newCutter As Tool = New Tool("Cutter", Tool.NType.Type)
                    newTool.Nodes.Add(newCutter)
                    For Each Cutter As XElement In Cutters
                        Dim Cutter_ID As String = Cutter.Attribute("ID")
                        newCutter.Nodes.Add(New Tool(Cutter_ID, Tool.NType.Part))
                    Next Cutter
                End If

                If Not element.Element("Holder") Is Nothing Then
                    Dim Holders As List(Of XElement) = element.Element("Holder").Elements("Reference").ToList()

                    Dim newHolder As Tool = New Tool("Holder", Tool.NType.Type)
                    newTool.Nodes.Add(newHolder)
                    For Each Holder As XElement In Holders
                        Dim Holder_ID As String = Holder.Attribute("ID")
                        newHolder.Nodes.Add(New Tool(Holder_ID, Tool.NType.Part))
                    Next Holder
                End If
            Next element
        Else
            ' Here you need to pull the data from the XmlNode based on the
            ' type of node, whether attribute values are required, and so forth.
            inTreeNode.Text = (inXmlNode.ToString()).Trim
        End If
    End Sub
    Sub ExpandToLevel(nodes As TreeNodeCollection, level As Integer)
        If level > 0 Then
            For Each node As TreeNode In nodes
                node.Expand()
                ExpandToLevel(node.Nodes, level - 1)
            Next node
        End If
    End Sub
    Sub treeView1_AfterExpand(sender As Object, e As TreeViewEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.AfterExpand
        If Not e.Node.Parent Is Nothing Then
            e.Node.ExpandAll()
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
Public Class Tool
    Inherits TreeNode

    Enum NType
        Root
        Tool
        Type
        Part
    End Enum

    Public NodeType As NType
    Sub New(type As NType)
        NodeType = type
    End Sub
    Sub New(text As String, type As NType)
        NodeType = Type
        Me.Text = text
    End Sub
    Private m_ID As String = ""
    Public Property ID As String
        Get
            Return m_ID
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_ID = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private m_Teeth As String = ""
    Public Property Teeth As String
        Get
            Return m_Teeth
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Teeth = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private m_Type As String
    Public Property Type As String
        Get
            Return m_Type
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Type = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private m_Description
    Public Property Description As String
        Get
            Return m_Description
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Description = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Function Add(text As String) As Tool
        Me.Text = text
        Return Me
    End Function

End Class
Public Class NodeSorter
    Implements IComparer

    Public Shared ReadOnly DefaultSorter As New NodeSorter

    'Create a node sorter that implements the IComparer interface. 
    'Compare the length of the strings, or the strings 
    'themselves, if they are the same length. 
    Public Function Compare(x As Object, y As Object) As Integer Implements System.Collections.IComparer.Compare

        Dim tx As Tool = CType(x, Tool)
        Dim ty As Tool = CType(y, Tool)

        If tx.NodeType = Tool.NType.Tool And ty.NodeType = Tool.NType.Tool Then
            'Compare the length of the strings, returning the difference. 
            If tx.Type.Length <> ty.Type.Length Then
                Return tx.Text.Length - ty.Text.Length
            End If

            'If they are the same length, call Compare.
            If tx.Type = ty.Type Then
                Return String.Compare(tx.Teeth, ty.Teeth)
            Else
                Return String.Compare(tx.Type, ty.Type)
            End If
        Else
            If tx.NodeType = Tool.NType.Part And ty.NodeType = Tool.NType.Part Then
                Return String.Compare(tx.Text, ty.Text)
            Else
                Return 0
            End If
        End If

    End Function
End Class
​
```